# Accessing $row (from num_rows) variable in different PHP sections -Solved -

Tags: php, modal-dialog

*Solved*

I am working on a modal and what to show the data of a record from a database. The button in the code opens the modal.

Code that shows the list of records:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, eventName, evLocation, evDTime, evNotes, Approved FROM events WHERE CreaterId = '{$_SESSION["userid"]}' ORDER BY evLocation";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        global $row;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<ul><li>Title: '.$row["eventName"].'</li><li>Location: '.$row["evLocation"].'</li><li>Time: '.$row["evDTime"].'</li><li>Details: '.$row["evNotes"].'</li><button id="myBtn">View</button><br></ul>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "<br>"."0 results";
    }
```

Then for the modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h1>Event</h1>
        <h4>Title: <?php echo $row["eventName"];?></h4>
        <h4>Address: </h4>
        <h4>Timing: </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I connect the `$row["eventName"]` of the modal to the query.

With some playing around I have a fix:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, eventName, evLocation, evDTime, evNotes, Approved FROM events WHERE CreaterId = '{$_SESSION["userid"]}' ORDER BY evLocation";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            global $yourEvent;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $yourEvent = $row["eventName"];
                echo '<ul><li>Title: '.$row["eventName"].'</li><li>Location: '.$row["evLocation"].'</li><li>Time: '.$row["evDTime"].'</li><li>Details: '.$row["evNotes"].'</li><button id="myBtn">View</button><br></ul>';
                echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal"><div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span><h1>Event</h1>';
                echo '<h4>Title: '.$row["eventName"].'</h4>';
                echo '</div></div><script src="script.js"></script>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<br>'.'0 results';
        }
```

Comment: There is no point tagging a RDBMS... its not part of the solution.

Comment: If you solved it, then please add an answer explaining how... otherwise delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, eventName, evLocation, evDTime, evNotes, Approved FROM events WHERE CreaterId = '{$_SESSION["userid"]}' ORDER BY evLocation";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            global $yourEvent;
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $yourEvent = $row["eventName"];
                echo '<ul><li>Title: '.$row["eventName"].'</li><li>Location: '.$row["evLocation"].'</li><li>Time: '.$row["evDTime"].'</li><li>Details: '.$row["evNotes"].'</li><button id="myBtn">View</button><br></ul>';
                echo '<div id="myModal" class="modal"><div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span><h1>Event</h1>';
                echo '<h4>Title: '.$row["eventName"].'</h4>';
                echo '</div></div><script src="script.js"></script>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<br>'.'0 results';
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).